# A strange gap in jQuery touchmove() distance

Tags: jquery

I have written a code that logs the distance of touch move in pixels.

As I move my finger left, what I get in console is "0,-9,-10,-11,-12, etc". Every time there is this strange gap between 0 and -9. **Why?** The code isn't complicated, there must be something going on that I don't understand.

Here's my code:

```
let move = {'x':0, 'startX':0};
let body = $('body');

$(document).ready(function(){
 
   //when touch starts, record initial position and the move distance of 0
   body.on('touchstart', function (e){
      //get finger X position
      if(typeof e.clientX !== 'undefined'){
         move.x = e.clientX;
      } else {
         move.x = e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
      }
    
      //record initial position and move distance
      move.startX = move.x;
      move.x = move.x - move.startX;

      //log
      console.log(move.x);
   });

   //when touch move continues, calculate distance
   body.on('touchmove', function (e){
      //get finger X position
      if(typeof e.clientX !== 'undefined'){
         move.x = e.clientX;
      } else {
         move.x = e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
      }
    
      //record move distance
      move.x = move.x - move.startX;

      //log
      console.log(move.x);
   });

   //when touch ends, reset data
   body.on('touchend', function (){
     some = {'x':0, 'startX':0};
   });
});
```

**Update.**
This seems to work:

```
function reset(){return{'x':0, 'startX':null};} 
let some = reset();
$(document).ready(function(){
   body.on('touchmove', function (e){
      let pos = typeof e.clientX !== 'undefined' ? some.x = e.clientX : e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;

      some.startX = some.startX !== null ? some.startX : pos;
      some.x = pos - some.startX;
      console.log(some);
   });

   body.on('touchend', function (){some = reset();});
});
```

Comment: Most likely a system-level setting so that the OS can easily differentiate between taps and accidental drag events.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Doesn't seem logical, there are many things that need to be dragged smoothly, which can't be done with a jump of 10 pixels. Imagine a Youtube time marker being off by 10 pixels...

Comment: It won't be off when dragging is actually happening, it's just the tolerance when the drag event starts.